# Collapse not working when in toggler menu

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar that switches to a toggler hamburger menu in smaller screens. But when i press any of the nav-links when i am inside the toggler menu in smaller screen, the collapse is not working. I want the menu to close. Do anyone know what the issue is and how i have fix it? I am new to web development and learing, so be kind haha :)

See my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg shadow-lg primarycolor ">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      
      <a class="navbar-brand d-lg-none" href="tel:+357 00000"><i class="bi bi-telephone pe-2"></i><span class="callme">+357 000000</span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#" >Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#Hours" >Hours & Locations</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#story" >Our Story</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#menufilter" >Menu</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery" >Photos</a>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >Other services</a>
          


            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
          <li >
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#catering" >Catering</a>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#franchise" >Franchise</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#job" >Work with us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#footer" >Contact us</a>
          </li>
          
            
          
          
        </ul>

        <div class="d-flex">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/s/" target="_blank"><h1 class="bi bi-facebook pe-3 pt-3 " ></h1></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com//" target="_blank"><h1 class="bi bi-instagram pt-3 " ></h1></a>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

These are my links:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda&family=Sora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <script>src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mixitup/3.3.1/mixitup.min.js" ></script>
```

I tried adding the below code. The collapse worked, but then the dropdown menu is not working.

```
<script>
  $('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');

    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's your goal? You want to close the menu when a link inside the dropdown is clicked?

Comment: exactly. Also when any other nav-link is clicked. Not working on either.